# Foreign Language Characters decode in Java **& iacute;**

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to display characters of foreign languages in jasper reports. The reports passes the text to java code for RTF formatting. Unfortunately the mysql database returns decoded string like below with spaces removed

**& iacute;**

what I want to display is

**í**

Any suggestions how to do it with java?

text: **bebida fría**

from database: **bebida fr& iacute;a**

Comment: Honestly, your problem is not how to decode HTML entities using Java, but that the HTML entities somehow ends up like that in the database. Why don't you fix whatever writes data to the database, so that the text is stored properly?

Comment: Its an existing product with a vast range of modules .. In the long run yes this would be the solution .. as << >> are coming in entity form ... But currently Joop's Solution fits best .. Thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That are HTML entities. You can use [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from apache commons library.

Still remains to see how your RTF handles Unicode.

Comment: At first i was ignoring this answer as I was unfamiliar with this library and didnt know how it would react with my RTF etc .. but it worked like a charm .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you could use the unicode literal,

```
System.out.println("bebida fr\u00EDa");
```

Output is (the requested)

```
bebida fría
```

Comment: The text is coming from database I want to decode the encoding on java

Comment: That's an HTML entity. You can try [Joop](http://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25913962/2970947), but I don't think it handles entities very well.

Comment: Isnt there anything where i set the encoding of string retrieved from database and i get my desired output?

Comment: No. Html entities aren't java character encodings.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in the javadoc of EscapeUtils they mention `"&ccedil;"` - have you contrary experiences? (I always doubt such exhaustive conversions; there are so many named entitites.)

Comment: @JoopEggen I've had issues in the past, but they may well have fixed them.

Comment: Thanks will let me be careful; unescapeHtml3+unescapeHtml4 is also not so straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

Check database table encoding. Also you can try to encode your string with proper encoding.

```
 ByteBuffer encode = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString);
 String encodedStr = new String(encode.array());
```

Comment: can i get back the string from ByteBuffer ?

Comment: @Rafay Did you check which encoding is set on the table in database?